# Autosys JIL creation failed

Tags: autosys, jil

When trying to create JIL file for update job command, getting the below error. But, the job is the valid one.

```
Due to the following 1 validation failures, no JIL has been generated.

1) Job_name??????:
 1   Use of update job is not valid here because Job_name?????? does not exist

Job details:

update_job: Job_name    job_type: cmd
machine: machine_name
owner: owner_details
permission: gx,wx
alarm_if_fail: y
alarm_if_terminated: y
send_notification: n
std_out_file: "C:\Users"
std_err_file: "C:\Users"
command: ""command_details""
```

tried to update job owner details.